# Intern: Finding Dynamically Generated ID's Using For Attribute

Tags: intern

I'm using the Intern with a website that dynamically generates IDs for input boxes, buttons, menu items, etc. The issue that I am facing is that I want to be able to find the "for" attribute of a label and find the DOM element it is pointing to. I want to find the input that is associated with the label. Is this possible with the intern? Or how would I write this test case?

```
     <div> 
<label for="element_1x12">
</label>
<input id="element_1x12">
</input>
<label for="element_1x13">
</label>
<input id=element_1x13">
</input>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a way to select the element, you could do something like:

```
// find the label somehow
.findByCssSelector(...)
.getAttribute('for')
.then(function (value, setContext) {
    return this.parent
        // pop the previously found element off the context stack
        .end()
        // find the input, which has an id equal to the label's for
        .findById(value)
        // set the context to the found input
        .then(function (input) {
            setContext(input);
        });
})
// do stuff with the input
```